# Using two profile provider in one mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I have two MVC application. say Public and private applications.
I want to be able that users register on public application, and administrator validate and edit and .. them on private application.

The private site has its own Membership/Role and profile provider which works well.

The public site has Membership/Role and Profile providers and I want to use these providers in private site so I can change the status of public users on private site.

I have several problems working with Public providers inside private application.

Is there any sample, information, on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to share the same database. Configure both projects to use the same connection string and use the same tables.

Comment: Then I am exposing private data to public web site and from a security point of view, I don't want to do this. I want them to be seperate.

Comment: The fact that you are sharing the same database between your public and private site doesn't mean that you ar exposing yourself to any security treats. What the public sees is your public facing web site. So all you need to do is to ensure that this site is secure enough.